# DateTime conversion error on insert into OrientDB

Tags: sql, debugging, datetime, insert, orientdb

> Error on conversion of date '2014-03-09T02:42:09.893' using the
>   format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS

The type of error here is `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OQueryParsingException`.

I set the DateTime format using:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATETIMEFORMAT yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Further, I know this is a bug with Orient vs the Node API I use because this also fails in the console:

> INSERT INTO User ("settings", "acceptedTerms", "activitiesCount",
>   "appFirstUseDate", "birthday", "email", "equipment", "feedOption",
>   "followerCount", "followingCount", "followingFeedLastReadAt",
>   "gender", "goal", "height_unit", "height_val1", "height_val2",
>   "kitchenSinkBadgesSeen", "lastRatePrompt", "lastVersionUsed", "level",
>   "numReferrals", "platform", "popularFeedLastReadAt", "postCount",
>   "seenHamburgerInstructions", "seenRatePrompt", "stream", "timezone",
>   "unsubscribedFromWorkoutEmails", "username", "weight", "weight_unit",
>   "createdAt", "updatedAt", "objectId", "ACL", "sessionToken") VALUES
>   ({"__type":"Pointer","className":"Settings","objectId":"K9X5P470hF"},
>   true, 10, {"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-03-09T03:37:53.270Z"},
>   {"__type":"Date","iso":"2000-03-29T00:00:00.000Z"},
>   "REMOVED@gmail.com", {"1":[6,8,4]}, 1, 0, 0,
>   {"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-03-12T00:32:11.245Z"}, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3,
>   ["activity","schedule","findfriends","log","share","workouts/new","profile/l8QOwljKWh","editProfile","progress","workouts/today"],
>   {"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-04-08T22:23:47.799Z"}, "2.4.3", 2, 0, 1,
>   {"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-04-08T22:23:45.070Z"}, 10, true, true,
>   "b", "America/Havana", true, "hannah00329", 128, 1,
>   "2014-03-09T02:42:09.893", "2014-04-08T22:43:27.086", "l8QOwljKWh",
>   {"*":{"read":true},"l8QOwljKWh":{"read":true,"write":true}},
>   "t7h4bpx5ri8oyd3vfdt1l7e0b")

With the same error:

> Error:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OQueryParsingException:
>   Error on conversion of date '2014-03-09T02:42:09.893' using the
>   format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS

Most other DateTimes work, but for some reason 1 in every 10000 fails with this error.

The other DateTimes in my table look exactly the same:

```
2013-06-28T04:50:35.717
2013-07-03T08:16:10.713
2012-12-27T19:56:52.030
```

EDIT:

Upon further investigation, it looks like 2pm on March 9th is doomsday...

```
SUCCESS:
2013-06-28T04:50:35.717Z
2013-07-03T08:16:10.713Z
2012-12-27T19:56:52.030Z

ERROR:
2014-03-09T02:42:09.893Z
2014-03-09T02:11:49.764Z
2014-03-09T02:02:43.987Z
2014-03-09T02:10:39.408Z
2014-03-09T02:37:10.196Z
2014-03-09T02:40:46.492Z
2014-03-09T02:22:26.589Z
```

EDIT:

Here are my OrientDB settings

```
--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
 NAME                           | VALUE                                              |
--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
 Name                           | null                                               |
 Version                        | 9                                                  |
 Date format                    | yyyy-MM-dd                                         |
 Datetime format                | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss                                |
 Timezone                       | America/Toronto                                    |
 Locale Country                 | US                                                 |
 Locale Language                | en                                                 |
 Charset                        | UTF-8                                              |
 Schema RID                     | #0:1                                               |
 Index Manager RID              | #0:2                                               |
 Dictionary RID                 | null                                               |
--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you display your timezone and locale settings? Use from console the "info" command.

Comment: @Lvca I forgot to respond, but I added the info. This is by far the weirdest error I've gotten so far :\

Comment: I agree, very weird, specially because we totally use the Standard Java API to do that. I've open a new issue to track it better: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2014-03-09T02:00:00 -> 2014-03-09T03:00:00` does not exist when incorporating Daylight Savings Time (DST).

Because that specific time is impossible when using DST, the error was in transferring the data from a database that allowed it to one that didn't. The reason Parse allows it is because they use Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), which does not change with DST.

The fix in OrientDB is as follows:

```
-- set timezone to utc
ALTER DATABASE TIMEZONE UTC
```