# OrientDB: DateTime conversion issue on SELECT in python with different timezone between server and db

Tags: python, orientdb, timestamp-with-timezone

My System and relevant settings:

- Linux (tried both in Ubuntu and Debian)
- Python 2.7.11
- pyorient 1.4.6a0
- OrientDB 2.1.8
- Studio 2.1
- Server timezone "Europe/Rome" (CET/CEST)
- OrientDB timezone "UTC"

Due to datetime inserting problems like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562133/datetime-conversion-error-on-insert-into-orientdb/25252018#25252018) I had to set the OrientDB timezone to "UTC":

```
ALTER DATABASE TIMEZONE UTC
```

Having the server timezone set to "Europe/Rome" creates some problems when executing SELECT on a datetime object in python. For example:

```
select distinct(tstamp_ini) as ini from Fct order by ini desc limit 1
```

in Studio the command returns what I expect:

```
2016-03-22 12:00:00
```

while in python I have a different result:

```
print result[0]
{{'ini': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 22, 13, 0)},'version':0,'rid':'#-2:139359'}

res=result[0].ini
print res
2016-03-22 13:00:00
print type(res)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
print res.tzinfo
None
```

I'd like the resulting datetime to be the same in python as in Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/issues/176) in pyorient (serializations.py) dates and datetimes are encoded and decoded using local time. This create several problems as described in the link and also the one described in the question.

A possible solution is to change serialization.py so that everything is treated as UTC.

In

```
def _encode_value(self, value):
```

add

```
from calendar import timegm
```

for datetime change

```
elif isinstance(value, datetime):
  ret = str(int(time.mktime(value.timetuple())) * 1000) + 't'
```

to

```
elif isinstance(value, datetime):
  ret = str(int(timegm(value.timetuple())) * 1000) + 't'
```

for date change

```
elif isinstance(value, date):
  ret = str(int(time.mktime(value.timetuple())) * 1000) + 'a'
```

to

```
elif isinstance(value, date):
  ret = str(int(timegm(value.timetuple())) * 1000) + 'a'
```

in

```
def _parse_number(self, content):
```

for date change

```
if c == 'a':
  collected = date.fromtimestamp(float(collected) / 1000)
```

to

```
if c == 'a':
  collected = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(collected) / 1000).date()
```

for datetime change

```
elif c == 't':
  collected = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(collected) / 1000)
```

to

```
elif c == 't':
  collected = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(collected) / 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that in your configuration you have set timezone to "Europe/Rome" ?

[image]

Comment: The DB timezone is GMT, but I need it in GMT. The problem is caused by the fact that the server and the DB timezone are different, but it seems to appear only in python and not in Studio.